# How to make a new dataframe that contains records from a particular column of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image: df]

new_df columns:

| district | AD1 | AD2 | AD3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alappuzha | Kottayam | Ernakulam | Pattanamtitta |
| Ernakulam | Kottayam | Alappuzha | Thrissur |
| Idukki | Pattanamtitta | Kottayam | Alappuzha |

Comment: please show us what you have tried already and add formating to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#create counter column
df['g'] = df.groupby('District1').cumcount().add(1)

#filter out first row per group
df = df[df['g'].gt(1)].copy()

#pivoting
df = df.pivot('District1','g','District2').add_prefix('AD')
```